# linq to xml validation against a DTD file in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a xml file that has

I am using linq to xml for parsing this xml. I have searched for validation of xml in linq to xml and most of the examples I get are validation against a xsd file.

Can please anyone tell me how to use linq to xml for validation against a DTD file.

Thanks.

Much obliged

Comment: i have xml file that has <!DOCTYPE REQUESTS SYSTEM "../Example1.dtd">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [XDocumentType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocumenttype.aspx):

> LINQ to XML will not validate a document against a DTD, but you can use a validating [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) to perform DTD validation if necessary.

So it sounds like you'll need to validate the Xml using an `XmlReader` before trying to read it using Linq to XML